# How to replace one Fragment with another on List item click?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a support `Action Bar` with two `Tabs`, one tab displays recent video clips, the other tab is a search function to find video clips. I'm new to Fragments, and what I can't get to work is replacing the Search and Recent Fragments with the Video playing Fragment on list item click in the main container Fragment. Here's the container Activity:

```
public class SearchInterface extends ActionBarActivity {
ActionBar bar_AB;
Tab tab1, tab2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    setContentView(R.layout.frag1_main6);
    setupTabs();

}// --- END onCreate
private void setupTabs() {
    bar_AB = getSupportActionBar();
    bar_AB.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    bar_AB.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    tab1 = bar_AB
            .newTab()
            .setText("Recent")
            .setTag(RECENT_TAB_TAG)
            .setTabListener(
                    new SupportFragmentTabListener<SSIRecentFrag>(
                            R.id.frag6_main_FL, this, RECENT_TAB_TAG,
                            SSIRecentFrag.class));
    bar_AB.addTab(tab1);
    bar_AB.selectTab(tab1);

    tab2 = bar_AB
            .newTab()
            .setText("Search")
            .setTag(SEARCH_TAB_TAG)
            .setTabListener(
                    new SupportFragmentTabListener<SSISearchFrag>(
                            R.id.frag6_main_FL, this, SEARCH_TAB_TAG,
                            SSISearchFrag.class));
    bar_AB.addTab(tab2);

}

}
```

And here's the container XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frag6_main_FL"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And then the Recent and Search Fragment Activities both look like this (this is the Search Activity):

```
public class SSISearchFrag extends Fragment {
View searchRootView;
EditText searchbox_ET;
LinearLayout list_LL;
Button search_BTN;
DBAdapter dbHelper;
ListView s_LV;

Cursor getPathCursor;
String cursorSDFStr = null;
String cursorCalDateStr = null;
String cursorURLStr = null;
String cursorTitleStr = null;
String cursorVerseStr = null;

FragmentManager fragMan;
FragmentTransaction fragTrans;
Fragment searchListFrag;
SSIVideoFrag video_FRG;
final String SEARCH_TAB_TAG = "searchTag";
Fragment recentListFrag;
Callback fragBackPressed;

// --- Create the ROOT VIEW
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    searchRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ssi_search_frag,
            container, false);
    searchbox_ET = (EditText) searchRootView
            .findViewById(R.id.ssi_Search1_et1);
    search_BTN = (Button) searchRootView
            .findViewById(R.id.ssi_search_btn1);
    list_LL = (LinearLayout) searchRootView
            .findViewById(R.id.ssi_search_list_LL);
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);


    // --- Button
    search_BTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(search_BTN.getWindowToken(), 0);
            dbHelper = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
            dbHelper.open();
            String searchTermStr = searchbox_ET.getText().toString();
            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.searchDB(searchTermStr);

            if (cursor != null) {
                String[] columns = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_TITLE,
                        DBAdapter.KEY_CAL_DATE, DBAdapter.KEY_PATH,
                        DBAdapter.KEY_SDF, DBAdapter.KEY_VERSE,
                        DBAdapter.KEY_KEYWORDS };

                int[] to = new int[] { R.id.slp_title_tv, R.id.slp_date_tv,
                        R.id.slp_url_tv, R.id.slp_sdf_tv, R.id.slp_verse_tv,
                        R.id.slp_keywords_tv };

                SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        getActivity(), R.layout.slp_list_item, cursor, columns, to,
                        0);

                s_LV = (ListView) searchRootView
                        .findViewById(R.id.ssisearch_list_lv);
                s_LV.setEmptyView(searchRootView
                        .findViewById(R.id.ssiempty_list_tv));
                s_LV.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }                   
            dbHelper.close();
            //--- onClick

            // --- pass to ListVideo
            s_LV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    getPathCursor = (Cursor) s_LV
                            .getItemAtPosition(position);
                    cursorSDFStr = getPathCursor.getString(getPathCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow("sdfdate"));
                    cursorCalDateStr = getPathCursor.getString(getPathCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow("caldate"));
                    cursorURLStr = getPathCursor.getString(getPathCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow("path"));
                    cursorTitleStr = getPathCursor.getString(getPathCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow("title"));
                    cursorVerseStr = getPathCursor.getString(getPathCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow("verse"));

                    //--- video fragment here
                    fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
                    searchListFrag = fragMan.findFragmentByTag(SEARCH_TAB_TAG);
                    if(searchListFrag != null)fragTrans.remove(searchListFrag);
                    video_FRG = new SSIVideoFrag();
                    fragTrans.replace(R.id.frag6_main_FL, video_FRG);
                    fragTrans.addToBackStack(SSIVideoFrag.TAG);
                    fragTrans.commit();


                }

            });//--- END onClick

        }
    });//--- END Button




    return searchRootView;
}// --- END Create the ROOT VIEW

}
```

The Recent and search functions work, it's when I click on a list item that I get a `NullPointerException`. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post the logcat please

Comment: fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();

where have you declared FragmentTransaction and FragmentManager?

Comment: Push to backstack? Why? I thought video should replace the former one. And try to add instead of replace and comment out pushing to backstack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably having a null pointer because the fragment manager is null. You first need to obtain the reference like this (since you're using ActionBarActivity I suppose you need the SupportFragmentManager):

`fragMan = getSupportFragmentManager();`

Also, if you want to replace the fragment, you don't need to remove it manually, so you just need:

```
fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();
video_FRG = new SSIVideoFrag();
fragTrans.replace(R.id.frag6_main_FL, video_FRG);
fragTrans.addToBackStack(SSIVideoFrag.TAG);
fragTrans.commit();
```

or you can shorten this:

```
video_FRG = new SSIVideoFrag();
fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag6_main_FL, video_FRG)
.addToBackStack(SSIVideoFrag.TAG).commit();
```